# Highcharts : x axis scaling issue

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting a chart using highcharts. It has a set of categories, lets say:

```
categories = ["a", "c", "h", "l"];
```

The categories are not equi-distant. Because, "a" corresponds to 5, "c" corresponds to "15", "h" corresponds to 16, "l" corresponds to 18.

The ticks on x axis are equi-distant. But, I want correct distance to be drawn between ticks, according to its value.

How to do this? Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: This is a 2nd question. I have categories = [12.36, 30.2653, 31.2345, 50.7815, 55.444, 67.7315]. The points are plotted correctly. But, the ticks drawn on x-axis are equidistant, which gives a wrong shape of graph. I want to display correct distance between points. How, to do this. Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Don't use categories - that's how categories displays. In your case use standard linear xAxis. Simply change data to: `series: [{ data: [ [12.36, value], [30...., value], [31, value], [50..., value], [55..., value], [67..., value] ] }]`. And don't forget to remove categories.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But, I didn't understand the solution. Can you please explain it in more details? Thank you. In your example, how the the series data is formed?

Comment: Like this: `data: [ [10, 20], [20, 40], [31, 33], [50, 33], [55, 22], [67, 11] ]`